# Builing TensorFlow for specific GPU architecture

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

I see `--copt=cuda` for building TensorFlow on a GPU. I would like to know if there is any way to specify a compute compatibility number? For example, I want to build for SM_50.

I didn't find a clear answer for that in the documents. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option about the compute capability after `./configure` (view sample configuration session from https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source?hl=en#configure_the_build):

> Please specify a list of comma-separated Cuda compute capabilities you
>   want to build with. You can find the compute capability of your device
>   at: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus. Please note that each
>   additional compute capability significantly increases your build time
>   and binary size. [Default is: 3.5,7.0] 6.1

Comment: Yes I have seen that. All I see is `--config=cuda`. I dont see any option related to sm compute number

Comment: If I didn't misunderstand these steps, the sm number is already configured before `bazel build`. When specifying the sm compute capability number during the `./configure` step, e.g. 5.0, then the building process will only build with SM_50.